# Named Relationship in Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel-4, model, eloquent, relationship

The title could be misleading but here is the problem:
I have a Recipe model and a themed Week model (Orange recipes week, Vegan week, etc). Now, I need to associate one recipe to each day of a week.
What I want is to have something like `Week::find(1)->monday`

I thought to achieve this by creating 7 relationships (one per day) in Week model, named monday, tuesday, etc, but it sounds verbose.
Another way could be to create a many to many relationship adding day in the pivot table, but then I didn't think I can access directly "the vegan week monday's recipe".

What do you think? Does anyone know a better way to achieve this?

Comment: Do you want to use "->monday", as if it runs a query? Well. I think you can use Scope(http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#query-scopes). About the other problems... can't help right now.

Comment: Well, scopes are a good point, but aren't exactly what I'm looking for. "->monday" is an example of the way I need to get access to Recipes, but I think it's better to clarify the real problem:
I will load an entire week of recipes (eagerly loading a week recipes, for example), then I also want to dispose of a logical way to retrieve each one based on the day, without querying 7 times.

Comment: You're not saying anything about how you want the recipes to be matched with the weekdays. It's not scope that you need here, rather a few methods that will fetch given recipe(s) from the related recipes collection, and that's totally up to you.

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk you're right.
Every week have one recipe for monday, one for tuesday, etc.
I will retrieve a week, then I will show a list of recipes like this:
- **Monday** -> Apple pie
- **Tuesday** -> New York Cheesecake
....
Is it sufficient?

Comment: @lucabartoli I understand your intentions, but you are still not saying how you match `Apple pie - Monday` so it's impossible to show you the way.

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk maybe i didn't understand what you are asking me, but i think this is part of the question. I'm not bound to anything, so i'm not forced to use (for example) a week model with 7 one to many relationship instead of something else. What i'm asking is how you would implement something like this, without particular constraints.

Comment: guessing: `Week hasMany Recipe`, then for a week you get `7 recipes`, then you create a method, eg. `getRecipeFor($weekday)` that returns one of those 7 recipes. It's up to you how you choose that one particular recipe for given weekday, that's what you didn't tell us. You can use accessor too, so you will be able to call `week->monday` instead of `week->getRecipeFor('monday')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are storing the weekday in the recipe table—such that a recipe will only ever belong to a single day at any time—then you can create a relation and a method in your `Week` model like this:

```
public function recipes()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Recipe');
}

public function recipesForDay($day)
{
    return $this->recipes()->where('day',$d);
}
```

...and then access each day by calling `Week::find(1)->recipesForDay('monday')->first();`

---

If, however, your `Recipe` table doesn't store any relation information (i.e. there is no `week_id` and `day` column in `recipes`, then you will need an intermediate `recipe_week` pivot table. The pivot table should look like this:

```
recipe_week
------------------------------------
recipe_id (integer/unsigned)
week_id   (integer/unsigned)
day       (integer, enum, or string)
```

In your `Week` model (**Week.php**):

```
public function recipes() 
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Recipe')->withPivot('day');
}

public function recipesByDay()
{
    return $this->recipes->keyBy('pivot.day');
} 

public function recipeForDay($day)
{
    return $this->recipes()->where('day', $day)->first();
}
```

Optionally, in your `Recipe` model (**Recipe.php**):

```
public function weeks() 
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Week')->withPivot('day');
}
```

With this setup, you can use `attach` to make the connection between recipes and weeks, specifying the day as an extra attribute. For example, to specify recipe #9 as the Monday recipe for week #1:

```
Week::find(1)->recipes()->attach(9, array('day' => 'monday'));
```

...which creates the relation, while leaving your `recipes` table untouched.

Then, to get a recipe for a particular day, you can query:

```
$recipe = Week::find(1)->recipeforDay('wednesday');
```

To get all recipes for a given week, and access them by their day without having to loop over them:

```
$recipes = Week::find(1)->recipesByDay();
var_dump( $recipes['monday']->name );
var_dump( $recipes['monday']->ingredients );
// etc...
```

Comment: I don't want to modify the Recipe model. Anyway I understand your approach, and it could be modified to not to touch the Recipe table.
But, there is one point: How can I eagerly load an entire week? I think this would require 7+1 queries to get the entire week recipes.

Comment: This approach assumes you are storing `week_id` and `day` in your `Recipe` model, where `week_id` is a foreign key connecting to `Week`. If that is the case, then you could load the entire week by `Week::with('recipes')->find(1)->get();`. If, however, no relation information is stored on the `Recipe` table, then you will need an intermediate pivot table to connect the two. That pivot table would include an additional `day` column.

Comment: Yes, the pivot table was the first approach i considered. I can also eager load all the recipes from an entire weeks.
I can access the day from a single recipe of the week collection `$recipe->pivot->day` but i don't know if it's possible to retrieve the recipe directly via day, without cycling trought the entire collection (like in an indexed array).

Comment: You can retrieve a recipe by day using `where`, which you can roll into a helper method called `recipeForDay`. Then you can call `$recipe = Week::find(1)->recipeforDay('wednesday');`...see edited answer.

Comment: Thankyou for your solution. Anyway, `$this->recipes()->where('day', $day)->first()` acts before querying, so I can't eagerly load the entire week and then get each single day. can I?

Comment: You could include a function on your `Week` model that uses the Collection method `keyBy`. This will allow you to retrieve a week's recipes (with 2 queries), then get the recipes by `day` using something like `$recipes['monday']`...see edited answer.